# How do I know how many tiles I've seen?

Tags: realm-of-the-mad-god

I want to get the fame bonus for seeing 1-million and 4-million tiles, but I'm not sure how many I've seen so far. Right now I'm just roaming around the map, but I'd like to know if I can stop now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As taken from the WildShadow Forums:

> Tiles count as "seen" if they are filled in on your minimap. The
>   circle of "seen" tiles on your minimap has a radius of 16 tiles. You
>   can do the math from there.

Otherwise, NO, you cannot see your current tile-seen count at all.

Comment: So do this mean I have to do it all at once?

Comment: Indeed. 4 Mil tiles means going around entire map.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this cumulative (ie all maps seen) or just one-shot (have to accomplish in current realm)?

Answer (score 1):

Use Muledump. It is easy to set up, but read the instructions carefully.

Comment: Even though I'm sure the question asker knows what you mean with your post, I can't edit this to a proper format because it makes no sense to me. Please try to use correct formatting and grammar.

Comment: Well I dont get it either